# Finding the order of pole of $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z-\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity-theory

The problem is Kreyszig 10ed international edition : 16.2 #9.

What is the order of the pole at $z=\pi$ of the function $f(z)$ below?
 $$f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z-\pi}$$
I thought that it will be a simple pole because $\sin z$ is analytic for all $z$$\in$$\Bbb C$ and $z-\pi$ has a 1st order zero at $z=\pi$.

But by expanding at $z=\pi$ using Laurent's Theorem, $$f(z)=\frac{-\sin(z-\pi)}{z-\pi}=\frac{-1}{z-\pi}\times\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n (z-\pi)^{2n+1}}
{(2n+1)!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (z-\pi)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
and $f(z)$ has no principal part so I can't determine the order of pole.

I think this problem occurred since $\sin \pi=0$ and the 'Poles and Zeros Theorem' wasn't applied.

What can I say about the order of the pole in this case?

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{z\to\pi} f(z) = \lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{\sin(z)}{z-\pi} = \lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{\sin(z) - \sin(\pi)}{z-\pi} \equiv \left.\frac{d\sin(z)}{dz}\right|_{z=\pi} = \cos(\pi) = -1$ so the singularity can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\sin x$ has a zero of order 1 at $\pi$, you would end up with a removable singularity at $\pi$.

Comment: Removable singularity is a new term for me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It has no pole.. As there are no principal part.. For pole principal part must exists and finite otherwise it ll have removal singularity or it ll be analytic... In our case it has removal singularity at $z=π$